# CentOs Nginx redirect https://www to https://

Tags: nginx, redirect, https, centos, no-www

Im using Nginx in centos. Im facing an issue with redirection.

I want to redirect all requests to `https://some-domain.com/url`

Im able to redirect

```
http://www.some-domain.com to https://some-domain.com
www.some-domain.com to https://some-domain.com
http://some-domain.com to https://some-domain.com
```

But im not able to redirect `https://www.some-domain.com`

conf file:

```
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name some-domain.com www.some-domain.com;
 ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/some-domain.com.chained.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/some-domain.com.key;

if ($host = https://www.some-domin.com) {
        return 301 https://some-domin.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your port 443 server bracket for https://www.some-domain.com so we can see where is the problem? Anonymitzed, ofc.

Comment: I guess i don't have server 443, i did everything in server 80

Comment: T'hats where https connections arrive, let me know if adding a 443 for that host works for you :)

Comment: Sure, let me add it

Comment: @flaixman added my server 443 section in the question, but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

It's best to separate two server brackets to evade the use of "if". Your problem was that you added "https://" to the host, when it's only www.some-domain.com what you needed to compare.

This example is simpler:

```
#Server bracket for https connections that come with host www.some-domain.com
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  www.some-domain.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/some-domain.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/some-domain.com.key;

    #redirects to https://non-www

    location / {
        return 301 https://some-domin.com$request_uri;
    }
}



# and then you can set a server bracket for non-www https connections.
# nginx will sort the connections depending on host for itself
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name some-domain.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/some-domain.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/some-domain.com.key;

    #Here it arrives 443 and without www, do what you wanted here
}
```